# Java newbie: how do i create a thread that controls my paintComponent method?

Tags: java, multithreading, jpanel, paintcomponent, runnable

this year i started java at school, i've been asked to create a program that with 3 threads paints 30 random circles (10 for each thread).

I don't know how to work with the paintComponent very well but here's what i've done:

```
class MioPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g); 
  Dimension dimCerchio1 = new Dimension(50, 50);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval((int) ((Math.random()*this.getWidth()) - (dimCerchio1.width)), (int) (Math.random()*this.getHeight() - (dimCerchio1.height )), dimCerchio1.width , dimCerchio1.height);
  }

  /*for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval((int) ((Math.random()*this.getWidth()) - (dimCerchio1.width)), (int) (Math.random()*this.getHeight() - (dimCerchio1.height )), dimCerchio1.width , dimCerchio1.height);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawOval((int) ((Math.random()*this.getWidth()) - (dimCerchio1.width)), (int) (Math.random()*this.getHeight() - (dimCerchio1.height )), dimCerchio1.width , dimCerchio1.height);
  }*/
}    

@Override
public void run() {

}
```

The run method is empty 'cause i don't actually know how i can work with both thread and paint

Here's the main:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    MFrame mframe = new MFrame("Cerchi casuali");

    Thread first = new Thread(new MioPanel());

    /*Thread second = new Thread(new MioPanel());

    Thread third = new Thread(new MioPanel());*/
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help, sorry for my english if something's wrong.

Comment: You kind of can't do this.  Java's Swing components are not thread safe.  You have to use a single thread, the Event Dispatch Thread, to do these updates.

Comment: So how can i do something similiar?

Comment: This is not a newbie assignment.  This assignment seems more appropriate for an intermediate or advanced Java class.

Comment: `...extends JPanel implements Runnable` Aaaaagh!  It burns my eyes!  Read about the _single responsibility principle_.  Each thing in your program (each package, each class, each object, each method, each variable, ...) should have just one reason to exist.  The reason for a `JPanel` to exist is to be a container for visible GUI elements.  The reason for a `Runnable` to exist is to provide the `run()` method that defines some _task_.  A program with a single object that fulfils both responsibilities will be harder to understand (harder to change) than a program that uses two separate objects.

Comment: _...i don't actually know how i can work with both thread and paint..._  You can't.  The Swing framework is not thread safe.  All of the painting has to happen in a single thread---the _event dispatch thread (EDT)_.  Swing programs may use other threads to perform computations that determine the appearance of GUI objects on the screen, but when the computation is done, the _worker threads_ use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r)` to request that the EDT call the methods that do the actual painting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't try and put everything in one class.

1. Create a class that starts the Swing components on the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  Create the JFrame in this class.
2. Create a DrawingPanel class that extends JPanel.  Add the DrawingPanel to the JFrame.
3. Create a Balls class that generates the x and y center and the radius of 10 balls.  You can use the java.awt.Point class to hold the center.  This class is a Java object.  It does nothing but hold the center and radius of the balls.
4. Create a Drawing class that implements Runnable.  Pass an instance of the Balls class to the Drawing class.
5. Create 3 instances of the Drawing class.  Pass the 3 instances of the Drawing class to the DrawingPanel.  Use the 3 instances in the paintComponent method.  **Do nothing but draw the balls in the paintComponent method.**
6. Pass the instance of the DrawingPanel to the 3 instances of the Drawing class.
7. Start 3 threads with these 3 instances after the GUI is completed.